# Activity Log from Einstein Bot

Tags: einstein

If the bot runs in to trouble at runtime, sometimes there's a connection error, other times it ends the chat no questions asked. And no error messages. I cant find anything in the debug logs. Are there runtime logs created for running bots.

Comment: I'm also getting same error....better you connect with Salesforce...

Answer (score 2):

The Einstein Chatbot runs with a user/license called "Cloud Integration User" that is not visible to the org. While the user is not visible, you can retrieve an Id using `UserInfo.getUserId()` to prove it's there. As well as see that the user is created by checking the audit logs after the bot is enabled.

If you need debug logs for backend actions, you can have the bot call Platform Events which run as the Automated Process user and add debug traces there.